# dojo/date/locale - Null dates

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to use dojo/date/locale to print date values, where NULL values appear as "" (blank). The script I am working on pulls features from a workflow database that may only be partially completed by users, the database currently stores 2 attributes, FileName and dateComplete. Currently, null date values print as 12/31/1969, even though null File Names are printed as "" (as preferred).

TLDR: I just need NULL dates to appear blank for a printout. Any recommendations? Thanks!

```
    var cTextElements = [];
    var gra = this.map.infoWindow.getSelectedFeature();
    var obj = { FileName: gra.attributes.FileName };
    cTextElements.push(obj);
    obj = { dateComplete: locale.format(new Date(gra.attributes.dateComplete), {
        selector: 'date',
        datePattern: "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy"
        })};
    cTextElements.push(obj);
    template.layoutOptions.customTextElements = cTextElements;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this solve your requirement:

```
var myDate = locale.format(new Date(gra.attributes.dateComplete));
myDate = myDate ? myDate : "";

obj = { dateComplete: myDate, {
    selector: 'date',
    datePattern: "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy"
 })};
```

Comment: if you pass "" for date then obj will have an invalid date like      
    dateComplete : "NaN/NaN/0NaN"

Answer (score 0):

12/31/1969 is an epoch date. Since `gra.attributes.dateComplete` is 0, it defaulted to epoch date. 
You can check null for `gra.attributes.dateComplete` and have some default date like

```
var myDate = new Date(gra.attributes.dateComplete);
myDate = myDate ? myDate : "12/31/2017";
```

or current date as

```
var myDate = new Date(gra.attributes.dateComplete);
    myDate = myDate ? myDate : new Date();
```